# Vanilla JS want to make a new progress bar on each click?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have this progress bar that gets created over a setTimeout of 2 seconds on click.
Now I want to create and append to DOM a new progress bar on every click. How do I do that? I tried using a promise but that just gets resolved after setTimeout - not sure if it doing anything at all. Can I use request animation frame here?

```js
(function() {
  const container = document.getElementById('container');

  const addBtn = document.getElementById('add');

  const progress = document.getElementsByClassName('progress');

  let promise = Promise.resolve();


  document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    // clone the progress made so far
    const newProgress = Object.assign({}, progress);

    // now add the new progress into container element, so its visible
    container.appendChild(newProgress[0]);

    promise = promise.then(() => new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        newProgress[0].classList.add('active');
        console.log(newProgress[0].classList)
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve();
        }, 2000);
      }, 0);
    }));
  });

})();
```

```css
#container {
  margin: 20px;
}

.progress {
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

.progress .bar {
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  transition: width 2s ease;
}

.progress.active .bar {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<button id="add">Add</button>

<div id="container"></div>

<div style="display: none">
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is it you're trying to do? Add a progress bar to the page each time a button is clicked? Are all the progress bars measuring the progress of the same event?

Comment: Are you sure you can use `Object.assign()` to clone DOM elements? You should use `cloneNode()`.

Comment: @duhaime yes same event - I am just trying to emit a new progress bar on each click - trying to warm up on dom.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any need to use `setTimeout` or `Promise` for this. Just create the element and append it directly in the event listener.

Comment: dint know about cloneNode(). thank you! @Barmar, since a while I want to get better with dom API but havent been of much success - in my components I end up using what I know already, tried reading MDN doc but its sooooo big! - do u know any other source where I can learn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended method for duplicating DOM nodes (ie the node matching `.progress`) is to use the [`.cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) method. In the case of your code, you'd also want to pass `true` to `.cloneNode()` to ensure that children of the progress node are also cloned.

So, if I understand your question correctly, then you want to clone the progress node and then delay assignment of the `.active` class to the clone. This can be achieved by making the following revisions to your code:

```js
(function(){
  const container = document.getElementById('container');

  const addBtn = document.getElementById('add');

  // use querySelector to aquire progress node for subsequent cloning
  const progress = document.querySelector('.progress');

  addBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

    // use cloneNode to duplicate existing node on DOM rather than 
    // Object.assign as you currently are
    const newProgress =  progress.cloneNode(true);
    
    container.appendChild(newProgress);
      
    // delay assignment of '.active' class to clone
    setTimeout(() => {    
      newProgress.classList.add('active');
    }, 50); 
  });
})();
```

```css
#container {
  margin: 20px;
}

.progress {
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

.progress .bar {
  width: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  transition: width 2s ease;
}

.progress.active .bar {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<button id="add">Add</button>

<div id="container"></div>

<div style="display: none">
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think he actually wants to show the new progress bar immediately, but delay the change to `active` class.

Comment: yes! I added true to .cloneNode so it deep clones the bar div too - but i dont see that 2s ease out anymore.This solution works in the sense it shows new progress bar each time, but the div with bar class needs to show up too, so the animation is visible. Could you please show me this?

Comment: @novembersky just updated answer - does this work for you?

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I was looking for! Just edited the timeout to be 50 instead of 2000 ms, since 2s is the time the bar should take to fill in, but bars should add immediately. Thank you so much!! I only needed to know why is it necessary to use querySelector?